# How to detect missing sequence and display the step?

Tags: c#

I have a standard sequence {"base", "stem", "backboard", "rim"}

I have a process that returns a list like {"stem", "base"}, {"stem", "backboard", "base", "rim"} ....

I need to detect if the sequence is going wrong by comparing the values of the returned list to the standard one.

Examples:

{"base"} - should return true

{"base", "stem"} - should return true

{"base", "backboard"} - should return false

{"stem", "base"} - should return true

{"backboard", "base", "stem"} - should return true

The order doesn't matter

I have tried putting in several if statements but nothing seemed right to me.

Here's my code:

```
if (tagList.Contains("base"))
{
    // do nothing
    if (tagList.Contains("stem"))
    {
        // do nothing
        if (tagList.Contains("bb"))
        {
            // do nothing
            if (tagList.Contains("rim"))
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
        else if (tagList.Contains("BB") && tagList.Contains("rim"))
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            // step -3 bb faulty
        }
    }
    else if (tagList.Contains("stem") && tagList.Contains("BB"))
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if (tagList.Contains("stem") && tagList.Contains("BB") && tagList.Contains("rim"))
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if (tagList.Contains("stem") && tagList.Contains("rim"))
    {
        // step-3 BB faulty
    }
    else
    {
        // step-2 stem faulty
    }

}
else if (tagList.Contains("base") && tagList.Contains("stem"))
{
    // do nothing

}
else if (tagList.Contains("base") && tagList.Contains("stem") && tagList.Contains("BB"))
{
    // do nothing
}
else if (tagList.Contains("base") && tagList.Contains("stem") && tagList.Contains("BB") && tagList.Contains("rim"))
{
    // do nothing
}
else if (tagList.Contains("base") && (tagList.Contains("BB") || tagList.Contains("rim")))
{
    // step-2 stem faulty
}
else
{
    // step-1 base faulty
}
```

Comment: Is the process return value a list of lists, or did you just give two sample results?

Comment: Either I don't understand what you are trying to do or I don't understand >{"base", "backboard"} - should return false

Comment: Why is `{"backboard", "base", "stem"}` true?

Comment: @vvilin {"base", "backboard"} - should return false as it is missing "stem"

Comment: @NetMage {"backboard", "base", "stem"} is true coz it contains base, stem, backboard

Comment: Also, why is `{"stem", "base"}` true?

Comment: @NetMage {"stem", "base"} is true coz it contains base and stem

Comment: So the _order_ doesn't matter? So the result lists are really sequences, then?

Comment: Yes the order doesn't matter

Comment: @HemachandraGhanta OHHH, ok. You should mention the order doesnt matter. What you mean is if you sort the list the same way that if you read them one by one they don't have a missing link. so `{"backboard", "base", "stem"}` sort to `{ "base", "stem", "backboard"}` and then it sees nothing missing in between

Comment: @Franck you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You (apparently) just want to know if a process result has all the elements up to the same number of elements in standard, *in any order*.

So, take the first *n* elements from the `standard`, and see if the result contains each one:

```
var okay = standard.Take(result.Count()).All(s => result.Contains(s));
```

To find out which are missing, use

```
var missing = standard.Take(result.Count()).Where(s => !result.Contains(s)).ToList();
```